# como definir a posiçao do item da lista do recycleview horizontal?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Bom dia, tenho um recycleview horizontal funcionando correto, porem quero fazer esse efeito do [exemplo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUAK6.jpg) , os itens começa quase no meio do recycleview ae depois de rolar para o lado ele preenche todo o espaço ficando assim [aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUqop.png) achei que seria apenas um padding-left, mas nao é nem  margin, alguem sabe ou como pesquisar para conseguir esse feito, agradeço obrigado.

fiz um video de um app que tem esse efeito para deixar mais claro 
[link](http://https://drive.google.com/open?id=1qZcA-_R_RfQZUZVkfjyX7TBCukE0REfm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você vai ter que adicionar um `Header` para o seu `Adapter`, este Header será o primeiro item que vai fazer a sua lista começar mais para a direita assim como vc quer.
[Este tutorial ensina como adicionar um Header na sua Recycler](https://inducesmile.com/android/add-header-to-android-recyclerview/)

Comment: perfeito, nunca imaginei que seria dessa forma vou seguir o tutorial, muito obrigado !.